# How to draw side by side boxplot using facet_wrap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, facet-wrap

I was looking for a solution to draw side by side `boxplot` using `facet_wrap` in `R`. Though there are lots of good solutions, however, I didn't come across any that i wanted. I decided to draw a picture of the `plot` that i would like to see of my two `data.frame`. `Data.frame` **C** has my *calibration* data for the four models of different meterics (i.e., KGE, NSE, PBIAS, and R-Sq) while `Data.frame` **V** has my *validation* data. I want to see a separate `plot` of each metrics using `facet_wrap` of the `ggplot2` functionality. Below is what i have done so far but its not taking me even closer.

```
graphics.off()
rm(list = ls())

library(tidyverse)

C = data.frame(KGE_M1 = runif(3, 0, 0.5), NSE_M1 = runif(3,0,0.5), R_Sq_M1 = runif(3,-1,0.3), PBIAS_M1 = runif(3, -0.25, 0.25),
               KGE_M2 = runif(3, 0.2, 0.7), NSE_M2 = runif(3,0.2,0.7), R_Sq_M2 = runif(3,-0.5,0.7), PBIAS_M2 = runif(3, -0.15, 0.15),
               KGE_M3 = runif(3, 0.3, 0.8), NSE_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), R_Sq_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), PBIAS_M3 = runif(3, -0.10, 0.10),
               KGE_M4 = runif(3, 0.5, 1), NSE_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), R_Sq_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), PBIAS_M4 = runif(3, -0.05, 0.05),
               Cal = rep("Calibration", 3))

V = data.frame(KGE_M1 = runif(3, 0, 0.5), NSE_M1 = runif(3,0,0.5), R_Sq_M1 = runif(3,-1,0.3), PBIAS_M1 = runif(3, -0.25, 0.25),
               KGE_M2 = runif(3, 0.2, 0.7), NSE_M2 = runif(3,0.2,0.7), R_Sq_M2 = runif(3,-0.5,0.7), PBIAS_M2 = runif(3, -0.15, 0.15),
               KGE_M3 = runif(3, 0.3, 0.8), NSE_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), R_Sq_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), PBIAS_M3 = runif(3, -0.10, 0.10),
               KGE_M4 = runif(3, 0.5, 1), NSE_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), R_Sq_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), PBIAS_M4 = runif(3, -0.05, 0.05),
               Val = rep("Validation", 3))

C = gather(C, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -Cal)
V = gather(V, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -Val)

ggplot(data = C)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x= Variable, y = Value))
  + facet_wrap(~Variable)
```

I would like to see a plot like below
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be with `facet_wrap`? If not, just make 4 different plots, and combine them using something like `grid.arrange()` in the `gridExtra` package

Comment: Thanks Jaris, there are a number of other `plots` which if using `grid.arrange` would be very laborious. That's why m priority is to use `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to split your `Variable` before plotting in order to have one variable for M1, M2, M3 M4 and one variable for your conditions:

```r
library(tidyverse)
C2 <- C %>% pivot_longer(., -Cal, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate(Variable2 = unlist(strsplit(Variable, "_M"))[2]) %>%
  mutate(Variable2 = paste0("Cal_M",Variable2)) %>%
  mutate(Variable1 = unlist(strsplit(Variable,"_M"))[1])  %>%
  rename(., Type = Cal)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Variable [6]
  Type        Variable  Value Variable2 Variable1
  <fct>       <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
1 Calibration KGE_M1    0.246 Cal_M1    KGE      
2 Calibration NSE_M1    0.476 Cal_M1    NSE      
3 Calibration R_Sq_M1  -0.978 Cal_M1    R_Sq     
4 Calibration PBIAS_M1  0.117 Cal_M1    PBIAS    
5 Calibration KGE_M2    0.544 Cal_M2    KGE      
6 Calibration NSE_M2    0.270 Cal_M2    NSE
```

Now, we are doing the same thing for the dataset `V`

```r
V2 <- V %>% pivot_longer(., -Val, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate(Variable2 = unlist(strsplit(Variable, "_M"))[2]) %>%
  mutate(Variable2 = paste0("Val_M",Variable2)) %>%
  mutate(Variable1 = unlist(strsplit(Variable,"_M"))[1]) %>%
  rename(., Type = Val)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Variable [6]
  Type       Variable   Value Variable2 Variable1
  <fct>      <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
1 Validation KGE_M1    0.459  Val_M1    KGE      
2 Validation NSE_M1    0.105  Val_M1    NSE      
3 Validation R_Sq_M1  -0.435  Val_M1    R_Sq     
4 Validation PBIAS_M1  0.0281 Val_M1    PBIAS    
5 Validation KGE_M2    0.625  Val_M2    KGE      
6 Validation NSE_M2    0.332  Val_M2    NSE
```

We can now bind them together:

```r
DF <- rbind(C2,V2)
```

Then, we can plot:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Variable2, y = Value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(.~Variable1, scales = "free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**EDIT: Rename x axis, add empty column to separate Calibration and Validation values**

To add an empty space between Calibration and Validation, you can simply add empty rows for each conditions of the Variable1 like this:

```r
DF <- as.data.frame(DF) %>% add_row(Type = rep("Empty",4),
                     Variable = rep("Empty",4),
                     Value = rep(NA,4),
                     Variable2 = rep("Empty",4),
                     Variable1 = unique(DF$Variable1))
```

Also, if you want to rename the x axis labels, you can use `scale_x_discrete`

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Variable2, y = Value, fill = Type))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(.~Variable1, scales = "free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("M1","M2","M3","M4","","M1","M2","M3","M4"))
```

[image]

Does it look what you are expecting ?

Comment: Hello dc37- thank you. this is quite close. I would like to see `Cal_M1` to `Cal_M4` as one group (closer together) followed by some space and then `Val_M1` to `Val_M4` as another group. Also, instead of calling at `Cal_M1` or `Cal_M2` i would like to name it as `M1` and `M2`. Like wise for `Val` data. Can we just fill it by `Variable` to have `legend`? That way I guess we do not need to name them individually as the `color` and `legend` would be unique?

Comment: I edited my answer to add an empty spaces between Calibration and Validation data and also to rename x axis. Let me know if it looks what you are expecting

Comment: Yes- that is exactly what i have asked for. thank you.

Comment: Hi dc37, Can we remove the `x-axis` label from the top two `subplots` ( from KGE & NSE plots) ? as i feel its just a repetition of the bottom figures.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to remove these upper x labeling without having to change the structure of the plot and obtaining the same plot than @Nareman Darwish.

Comment: @dc37 Hello, how can I draw a line to separate the two `Type` ?

Comment: @wut, you can maybe use `geom_vline` with `xintercept`being ""

Answer (score 2):

So here's a way with which you can do the required;

First we create the data that you have;

```
library(tidyverse)

# Creating first dataframe
C <- 
  data.frame(
    KGE_M1 = runif(3, 0, 0.5), 
    NSE_M1 = runif(3,0,0.5), 
    R_Sq_M1 = runif(3,-1,0.3), 
    PBIAS_M1 = runif(3, -0.25, 0.25),
    KGE_M2 = runif(3, 0.2, 0.7), 
    NSE_M2 = runif(3,0.2,0.7), 
    R_Sq_M2 = runif(3,-0.5,0.7), 
    PBIAS_M2 = runif(3, -0.15, 0.15),
    KGE_M3 = runif(3, 0.3, 0.8), 
    NSE_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), 
    R_Sq_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), 
    PBIAS_M3 = runif(3, -0.10, 0.10),
    KGE_M4 = runif(3, 0.5, 1), 
    NSE_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), 
    R_Sq_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), 
    PBIAS_M4 = runif(3, -0.05, 0.05),
    Cal = rep("Calibration", 3),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Creating second dataframe
V <- 
  data.frame(
    KGE_M1 = runif(3, 0, 0.5), 
    NSE_M1 = runif(3,0,0.5), 
    R_Sq_M1 = runif(3,-1,0.3), 
    PBIAS_M1 = runif(3, -0.25, 0.25),
    KGE_M2 = runif(3, 0.2, 0.7), 
    NSE_M2 = runif(3,0.2,0.7), 
    R_Sq_M2 = runif(3,-0.5,0.7), 
    PBIAS_M2 = runif(3, -0.15, 0.15),
    KGE_M3 = runif(3, 0.3, 0.8), 
    NSE_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), 
    R_Sq_M3 = runif(3,0.3,0.8), 
    PBIAS_M3 = runif(3, -0.10, 0.10),
    KGE_M4 = runif(3, 0.5, 1), 
    NSE_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), 
    R_Sq_M4 = runif(3,0.5,1), 
    PBIAS_M4 = runif(3, -0.05, 0.05),
    Val = rep("Validation", 3),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now we change format of the data and visualize it;

```
# Rename the variable to make it same
C <- rename(C, Identifier = Cal)
V <- rename(V, Identifier = Val)

data <- 
  # First we bind the two datasets
  bind_rows(C, V) %>%
  # We convert from wide format to long format
  gather(key = "Variable", value = "Value", -Identifier) %>%
  # We separate Variable into 2 columns at the last underscore
  separate(Variable, into = c("Variable", "Number"), sep = "_(?=[^_]+$)")

data %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Number, y = Value, 
                   group  = interaction(Identifier, Number), fill = Identifier)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Variable)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good one- thanks Nareman. Didn't even thought of that way.

Comment: Is there a way to rename `R-Sq` to `R2` where 2 is a `super script` of `R`?

Comment: mutate(Variable = ifelse(Variable == "R-Sq", "R2", Variable))

Comment: I like the way how you bring together the calibration and validation for each model (M).